# GTK+ standalone menu does not get shdown if not launched from terminal

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

The following program always works OK — shows the menu with one item — if launched from the terminal, but not if launched by the i3 window manager directly (when bound to a key).

In the latter case, most of the time it does print “Entering gtk main loop.”, but then simply does not get shdown; though approximately once per 20 key presses it does get shown!

Why?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static
void
deactivate_handler(GtkMenuShell *instance, gpointer user_data)
{
    (void) instance; (void) user_data; // unused parameters
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new();

    GtkWidget *item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Test");
    gtk_menu_attach(GTK_MENU(menu), item, 0, 1, 0, 1);

    g_signal_connect(menu, "deactivate", G_CALLBACK(deactivate_handler), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(menu);

    gtk_menu_popup(GTK_MENU(menu), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, gtk_get_current_event_time());

    fprintf(stderr, "Entering gtk main loop.\n");

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but useful: use the G_GNUC_UNUSED marco from the GLib to marke arguments as unused.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect calling `gtk_menu_popup` before `gtk_main` will lead to weird behavior. You're not changing data, like `gtk_widget_show_all` that changes a flag, you're actually trying to *do* actions.

One trick I see is switching to `GtkApplication` and run `gtk_menu_popup` in response to the `GtkApplication`'s `activate` signal. At that time you're already in the main loop.